# What is the correct approach to creating spatial weight matrices for a spatial lag/error model when some observations are very far from any others?

Tags: r, regression, spatial, weights

I am running a spatial regression model in R, but I am having trouble figuring out how to define a spatial weights matrix. There are two packages I can use, the package spdep has the function errorsarlm() which can carry out spatial lag or spatial error models, while the package sphet with spreg() can run these models as well but can find heteroscedasticity-consistent standard errors.

The problem I'm having is that spreg() doesn't take a weights matrix with any zero observations in it. If I use spreg(), then, I can use nb2listw() to generate spatial weights, but doing so requires me to increase the distance to being large enough that the most isolated observation has at least one neighbour. This isn't ideal I feel, as then some observations have many, many neighbours that are assigned equal weights. So instead I am using nb2listwdist() with inverse distance weighting "idw". In general however, I am having trouble understanding what the best approach is to creating a spatial weights matrix for a spatial problem. There are many introductory guides to spatial regressions online, and for the most part they use nb2listw(), which I find interesting as my expectation would be that a weighting matrix that takes distance from other observations into account would contain more information.